# Angular detect when user leaves application

Tags: javascript, angular, security

I've had a look around but I cannot seem to find the answer. Due to the *"security"* team at my company, they have stated that a website we have recently built, when a user navigates away from the website, we need to destroy the session.

Currently it's using a JWT token stored in the local browsers session, so when the user closes the browser the token will be destroyed.

So I know I can hook into `window.onbeforeunload` but this would also happen if the user refreshes the page, I don't think that would be acceptable behaviour for a website (refresh the page and now you are logged out). And there is also the `Reload Site?` popup that appears.

Does anyone know a way to detect that the user is navigating *away* from the angular app opposed to just reloading the page?

Comment: I don't see how you could distinguish the refresh from an actual leaving, but you could test storing the token in the session storage, that gets deleted when the user closes its browser. I'm not sure about a tab being closed though. Finally, you could also refuse the token once 10 min without requests have passed (this would be done in the back-end)

Comment: @trichetriche This was my initial thought. I was hoping for a answer to this question but I already know that I'm not going to get it!

Comment: @trichetriche if you open the page in another window or tab it will initialize a new session storage

Comment: @JEY so tab closure should erase the storage then, right ?

Comment: yes it's just a limitation. It's strange for the user to be logout when opening a new tab.